# Apex Class compile error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Map<Id,Application__c>

Tags: apex, tasks, compile-error

I have a relatively simple apex class that is failing to compile.  Please take a look and let me know if any of you have thoughts on what could be causing the issue...

```
public class TestScoreReviewClass {
/***************
 * When a new ACT or SAT test score is created, if
 * the student application decision is Decision Pending
 * or Postponed, create a task for the recruiter to
 * review the test scores
 ****************/
    Public static void sendTestScoreTask(Test_Score__c[] test_score){
        // Select the Contact.Id that ties to the Test_Score__c

        Set<string> contactId = new Set<string>();
        Set<ID> recID = new Set<ID>();

        for (Test_Score__c tz : test_score){
            if(tz.Contact__c != NULL) {
                contactid.add(tz.Contact__c);
            }
        }
        // Select the latest application tied to the new test score  
        Map<ID,Application__c> ApplInfo = new Map<ID,Application__c>([select Id, Student__c, Counselor_Id__c
                                  from application__c 
                                 where Student__r.Domestic_Or_International__c = 'Domestic' 
                                   and Application_Decision__c in ('Decision Pending','Postponed') 
                                   and Student__c in :contactid]);

   For (Application__c c : ApplInfo.Values() )
   {
      recID.add(ApplInfo.Counselor_Id__c);
   }

   Date dt = Date.today();
   List<Task> followupTasks = new List<Task>();
// Generate a list of tasks to be generated

   Map<ID, List<Task> > tsks = New Map<ID, List<Task> >();
   List<Task> tsksadd = New List<Task>();

   For ( Task t : [select ID, WhoId 
                     from Task where Status not in ('Completed') and Subject = 'Review New Test Score (ACT or SAT)'
                      and WhoId IN : contactId
                      and OwnerId IN : recID ] )
   {

      If (tsks.ContainsKey(t.WhoID) == true)
      {
         tsksadd = tsks.Get(t.WhoID); 
      }

      tsksadd.Add(t);
      tsks.Put(t.WhoID, tsksadd ); 


   }


   for (Test_Score__c test1 : test_score) 
   {
      Contact ApplContact = ApplInfo.get(test1.Contact__c);

      if (ApplContact.Id != null && ApplContact.Recruiter_Id__c != null) 
      {


         List<Task> taskss = tsks.Get(ApplContact.ID);
         If (taskss == null)
         {

            Task tasks = new Task(
            WhoId = ApplContact.Id,
            OwnerId = ApplContact.Recruiter_Id__c,
            Priority = 'Normal',
            Type = 'Email',
            ActivityDate = (dt.addDays(1)),
            Status = 'Not Started',
            Subject = 'Review New Test Score (ACT or SAT)');

            followupTasks.add(tasks);

          }
      }
   }


// insert the entire list
   if (followupTasks.size() > 0) {
      insert followupTasks;
   }
    }
}
```

I already checked the application query to ensure it was correct for our site.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get a field value from the map, instead of the record you are iterating. Change this line:

```
recID.add(ApplInfo.Counselor_Id__c);
```

to:

```
recID.add(c.Counselor_Id__c);
```